# R: Append Object to an Array: Why is Data Structure not Preserved?

Tags: r, list, vector, append

When I append an object to a vector or list, the structure of the appended object somehow gets mixed up. In my case I want to append the `predict()`result of a `glm()`model which is itself a **named list** ([according to the docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/predict.glm.html)):

> If `se.fit = TRUE`, a list with components
>
> `fit`:             Predictions, as for `se.fit = FALSE`.
>
> `se.fit`:          Estimated standard errors.
>
> `residual.scale`:  A scalar giving the square root of the dispersion used in computing
>   the standard errors.

Example setup:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5), param=c(1,2,1,2,1), y=c(3,6,5,8,8))
mdl <- glm(y ~ x + param, data=dat)
lvls <- c(1,2)
x <- seq(1,5, length.out=10)
```

I've tried several approaches

```
# 1st approach
pred1 <- c()
for(i in 1:length(lvls)) {
    prd <- predict(mdl, data.frame(x=x, param=lvls[i]), se.fit=TRUE)
    pred1 <- c(pred1, prd)
}    
print(attributes(prd))  # this returns what I expect
# $names
# [1] "fit"            "se.fit"         "residual.scale"
print(attributes(pred1[1]))
# $names
# [1] "fit"



# 2nd approach
pred2 <- list()
for(i in 1:length(lvls)) {
    prd <- predict(mdl, data.frame(x=x, param=lvls[i]), se.fit=TRUE)
    pred2[i] <- prd  # this raises an error 
}



# 3rd approach
pred3 <- list()
for(i in 1:length(lvls)) {
    prd <- predict(mdl, data.frame(x=x, param=lvls[i]), se.fit=TRUE)
    pred3 <- append(pred3, prd)
}
print(attributes(pred3[1]))
# $names
# [1] "fit"
```

As you can see, only the first named attribute `$fit` remains in the vector or list. I can't access `$se.fit` like I would expect:

```
pred3[1]$se.fit  # I would expect to be able to do this for the first prediction
# NULL
```

Instead, it seems that all named attributes of the original object were flattened into a sequence with a single attribute for each item

```
pred3[1]
# $fit
#        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10 
# 2.933333 3.466667 4.000000 4.533333 5.066667 5.600000 6.133333 6.666667 7.200000 7.733333 

pred3[2]
# $se.fit
#         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
# 0.3126944 0.2769618 0.2467901 0.2244334 0.2123744 0.2123744 0.2244334 0.2467901 0.2769618 0.3126944 

pred3[3]
# $residual.scale
# [1] 0.3651484

pred3[4]
# $fit
#        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10 
# 4.600000 5.133333 5.666667 6.200000 6.733333 7.266667 7.800000 8.333333 8.866667 9.400000 

pred3[5]
# $se.fit
#         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
# 0.3464102 0.3145315 0.2883185 0.2694301 0.2594708 0.2594708 0.2694301 0.2883185 0.3145315 0.3464102 

pred3[6]
# $residual.scale
# [1] 0.3651484
```

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I append the object 'as is'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer. I've just discovered the double bracket indexing `[[`

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-and-notations-for-accessing-the-elements-of-a-lis) explains the difference. The crucial thing:

> For lists, one generally uses `[[` to select any single element, whereas `[` returns a list of the selected elements.

I've played around with this and came to the solution:

```
# 4th approach - like 2nd but [[ instead [
pred4 <- list()
for(i in 1:length(lvls)) {
    prd <- predict(mdl, data.frame(x=x, param=lvls[i]), se.fit=TRUE)
    pred4[[i]] <- prd
}


pred4[[1]]$fit
#        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10 
# 2.933333 3.466667 4.000000 4.533333 5.066667 5.600000 6.133333 6.666667 7.200000 7.733333 

pred4[[1]]$se.fit
#         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
# 0.3126944 0.2769618 0.2467901 0.2244334 0.2123744 0.2123744 0.2244334 0.2467901 0.2769618 0.3126944 

pred4[[1]]$residual.scale
# [1] 0.3651484
```

I *think* I also understand why my 1st approach doesn't work. The explanation is [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) (`?Extract`)

> **Extract or Replace Parts of an Object**
>
> Description
>
> Operators acting on vectors, matrices, arrays and lists to extract or replace parts.
>   Usage
>
> ```
> x[i]
> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]
> x[[i, exact = TRUE]]
> x[[i, j, ..., exact = TRUE]]
> x$name
> getElement(object, name)
> ```

So the named entries of the `predict`-result-list are on the same level or *index dimension* where the vector does its append operation. *The extract / indexing methods are equivalent*. That means the `$names` are just aliases for the `[[index]]`. And so with single brackets I appended not the elements, but one list of 3 named elements to another.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
library('magrittr')
pred1 <- c()
for(i in 1:length(lvls)) {
  prd <- predict(mdl, data.frame(x=x, param=lvls[i]), se.fit=TRUE)
  pred1 %<>% append(prd)
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Returned the same as my 1st approach (appends the second 3 elements to the first 3 elements)